# CMD variable isn't resolved in for /r loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, file-rename

I'm tying to append the date to all files in all folders and subfolders named `archive` of every department of our enterprise.

So my code looks like this:

```
for /d %i in ("V:\*.*") do (if exist "%i\archive" (for /r "%i\archive\" %a in ("*.*") do echo ren "%~a" "%~na_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%%~xa"))
```

The problem is, that the variable `%i` only works for the `if`-statement, not for the `for /r`-loop.
It echos back:

```
if exist "V:\department1\archive" (for /r "%i\archive\" %a in ("*.*") do echo ren "%~a" "%~na_20191210%~xa")
if exist "V:\department2\archive" (for /r "%i\archive\" %a in ("*.*") do echo ren "%~a" "%~na_20191210%~xa")
```

So as you can see it does not resolve the `%i` in the second loop.

Can someone explain why this doesn't work?

The folder tree is as follows:

```
V:\department1\archive\file1.docx
V:\department1\archive\subfolder1\file1.docx
V:\department1\archive\subfolder2\file1.docx
V:\department1\stillneedthis\file1.docx
V:\department2\archive\file1.docx
V:\department2\archive\subfolder1\file1.docx
V:\department2\archive\subfolder2\file1.docx
V:\department2\stillneedthis\file1.docx
```

Comment: `*.*` is selecting directories which include a period, just use `*`. Also, to check for the existence of a directory as opposed to a file, you should include a trailing separator, e.g. `If Exist "DirectoryName\" (`. Please also note that in a batch file you need to escape the special character, `%` with another `%`, i.e. `%%i`.

Comment: `*.*` works too, but is not so clean code, so I changed it. And yes I i was just testing directly in the command line, in the batch it only works with the double-%. Thanks for your clean code advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work, as the FOR options neither support delayed nor FOR-parameter expansion.

With a helper function, you could use percent expansion.

```
for /d %%i in ("V:\*.*") do (
    if exist "%%i\archive" call :helper "%%~i"
)
exit /b

:helper
for /r "%~1\archive\" %a in ("*.*") do (
   echo ren "%~a" "%~na_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%%~xa"
)
```

Comment: Oh my god, now I see. Thank you so much! Works exactly as expected.

Comment: I would recommend, first of all taking the date and saving it as a string, e.g. `Set "today=%DATE:~-10%"`, then because the code above is currently incorrect, using `For /D %%i In ("V:\*") Do (If Exist "%%i\archive\" Call :helper "%%i")` and `For /R "%~1\archive" %%a In (*) Do (Echo Ren "%%a" "%%~na_%today:~-4%%today:~4,2%%today:~,2%%%~xa")`. I'd also mention that there's no code which predetermines whether your directories already contain a `_datestring` suffix so another run will continue to add those suffixes regardless of whether it already has one.